# Can't edit Freeform Pro entries via the CP

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am having an issue with editing entries via the CP.

When I change something (a text field) and hit submit, I get the spinner png for a second or two and then nothing. If I manually reload the page I can see the edits didn't stick. I don't see any console errors.

I upgraded to the latest of everything, still no luck.

Runnin:

EE 2.7.0
Freeform Pro 4.1.2

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Thats odd. Are you using Chrome? If so, try enabling logging of XHR calls and see if there is a PHP error occurring on the ajax validate in the console.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed this comment. I do have Chrome. I'm looking enabling XHR calls. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Okay, no error... I get: XHR finished loading: "http://sitename.com/admin.php?S=f3add5c0955dd54b49d4a3e789e77fff&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=freeform&method=save_entry".

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache (especially if you come from a Freeform upgrade)? We can't reproduce this on our side. Can you contact us at http://support.solspace.com with CP/FTP credentials so we can have a look? Please refer to this thread if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be having an issue with the [**Hon-ee Pot Captcha** extension](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hon-ee-pot-captcha). If you're not using it, I recommend disabling it. If not, try adding a custom field in your Freeform form with the name of your Hon-ee Pot field.

What gave it away was looking at the browser's console. After submitting the form in Freeform, look for a URL in the console which is the ajax URL used to save the data. At least in Chrome, click that URL, which will take you to the *Network* tab of the browser console. Click the same URL again there, and look at the *Preview* or *Response* tab, which will reveal the Hon-ee Pot Captcha error:

> Sorry, but we think you might be a robot.

Extra reading: This thread from the old Solspace forums: http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/7490/